# How can I remove an exact amount of duplicate values from an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

Here, i have an array with 5 numbers, and 3 (or more) of them are the same: `[1,1,4,2,1]`.

How can i get just the other two numbers from the array (in the example case, `[4,2]`)?

Here are some test cases:

```js
[1,1,4,2,1] => [4,2] or [2,4]
[5,5,1,5,5] => [1,5] or [5,1]
[3,4,3,4,3] => [4,4]
[6,6,6,6,6] => [6,6]
```

I did try something myself, i decided to count the numbers. I did make some progress, but don't know where to go next.

```js
function getUniques(arr) {
  const counts = {};
  arr.forEach(num => {counts[num] = (counts[num]||0) + 1});
  const uniques = [];
  Object.keys(counts).forEach(n => {
    if (counts[n] === 1)
      uniques.push(Number(n));
  });
  return uniques;
}
console.log(getUniques([1,4,2,1,1])) // [2,4]
console.log(getUniques([6,3,3,6,6])) // []
console.log(getUniques([5,3,5,5,5])) // [3]
console.log(getUniques([4,4,4,4,4])) // []
```

Comment: shouldnt your result from the third example just be `[3]`? hard to understand what is it that you exactly want, and also your attempt is missing

Comment: Should some order be maintained, of can the solution for the second one also be [5,1]?

Comment: In the `[1,1,4,2,1] → [4,2]` case you had removed the _first_ three duplicates. In the `[1,5,1,1,1] → [1,5]` you had removed the _last_ three duplicates.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine No, in the first case the last three duplicates were removed.

Comment: Count the number of occurrences mod 3 in an object or map, and create the result array with the new counts.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+remove+duplicates+from+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @jabaa Ah, okay, agreed

Comment: wow, the stack overflow community is so lovely and helpful  it gives me a reason to live

Comment: Ready to help. Can you clarify the points raised above? Does the contribution of jabaa help you to solve the problem?

Comment: yes, the output can have the two numbers in any order. and it has to be two numbers.

Comment: Ah I see the requirement that the input always has size 5.

Comment: @trincot i don't worry about that - i know that the input will have at least 3 of the same number

Comment: OK, so I voted to have the question reopened -- yes, it is important to react immediately to the comments you get after posting ,-)

Comment: Reopened the question. This actually is the first ever question I've seen to have been reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the array to maintain a counter for each unique value. You can use a `Map` or plain object for that purpose. But instead of a normal counter, make that count *modulo* 3:

```js
function removedTriplets(arr) {
  const counter = {};
  for (const value of arr) counter[value] = ((counter[value] || 0) + 1) % 3;
  return arr.filter(value => counter[value]-- > 0);
}

const tests = [
  [1,1,4,2,1],
  [1,5,1,1,1], 
  [3,3,3,3,3],
  [8,9,8,9,8],  
];

for (const arr of tests) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr), "=>", JSON.stringify(removedTriplets(arr)));
}
```

Comment: that's genius, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrences, find which numbers occur three or more times, and delete them:

```js
function removeThreeDuplicates(inputs) {
  const inputCopy = inputs.slice()
  const occurrences = Object.create(null)

  for (const [index, input] of inputCopy.entries()) {
    occurrences[input] ??= []
    occurrences[input].push(index)
  }

  for (const indexes of Object.values(occurrences)) {
    if (indexes.length >= 3) {
      const indexesToDelete = indexes.slice(0, 3)

      for (const index of indexesToDelete.reverse()) {
        inputCopy.splice(index, 1)
      }

      return inputCopy
    }
  }

  throw new Error('Unexpected input, expected an array of five numbers and three duplicates')
}

console.log(removeThreeDuplicates([1, 1, 4, 2, 1])) // => [4, 2]
console.log(removeThreeDuplicates([5, 5, 1, 5, 5])) // => [1, 5]
console.log(removeThreeDuplicates([3, 4, 3, 4, 3])) // => [4, 4]
console.log(removeThreeDuplicates([6, 6, 6, 6, 6])) // => [6, 6]
```